# How do I programmatically change ActionBar menuitem text colour?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have an actionBar with multiple items, I would like to change the colour of the text when the item is clicked.  Is there anyway to do this programmatically? Please provide and example or any resources.

Thanks

```
  public void catalogClick(MenuItem item){
     //highlight menuitem etc.

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this link which explains how to change menuitem text programmatically.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Style

Check for android:actionMenuTextColor for defining a style resource for text.

Comment: Is there a way to change it without defining a style resource?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked.

Answer (score 4):

To change without defining a style resource, we can use SpannableString.

```
    @Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            //To style first menu item
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(0);
    CharSequence menuTitle = menuItem.getTitle();
    SpannableString styledMenuTitle = new SpannableString(menuTitle);
    styledMenuTitle.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#00FFBB")), 0, menuTitle.length(), 0);
    menuItem.setTitle(styledMenuTitle);

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {

    Toast.makeText(this, item.getTitle() + " clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return true;
}
```

As you format the text style, you will get "Invalid payload item type" exception. To avoid that, override onMenuItemSelected, and use return true or false.

Reference:

[Android: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid payload item type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658725/android-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-invalid-payload-item-type)

http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.in/2013/02/solution-invalid-payload-item-type.html

Comment: I tried this and it had no effect. Does it work for you when compiled and run on Android 4.4?

Answer (score 1):

Try Firewall_Sudhan answer but iterating the submenu of the menu

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    SubMenu subMenu = menu.getItem(0).getSubMenu();
    for (int i = 0; i <  subMenu.size(); i++) {
        MenuItem menuItem = subMenu.getItem(i);
        CharSequence menuTitle = menuItem.getTitle();
        SpannableString styledMenuTitle = new SpannableString(menuTitle);
        styledMenuTitle.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), 0, menuTitle.length(), 0);
        menuItem.setTitle(styledMenuTitle);
    }
}
```