# How to change the font of Action Bar's Option Menu Items Title?

Tags: java, android, fonts

I m trying to change the Font style of menu item,so i wanted to set MenuItems font style is in "Century-Gothic".

Below is my code

**menu.xml**

```
 <item
        android:id="@+id/option_menu_item_1"
        android:orderInCategory="1"`enter code here`
        android:title="option_menu_item_1"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/option_menu_item_2"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:title="option_menu_item_2"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/option_menu_item_3"
        android:orderInCategory="3"
        android:title="option_menu_item_3"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
            Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class
                    .getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
            if (menuKeyField != null) {
                menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
                menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {     
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }
}
```

**color.xml**

```
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF00FF</color>
    <color name="skyBlue">#FF0000</color>
</resources>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/skyBlue</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

I m getting output like as show in below image

**OutPut**

[image]

But I want to change **MenuItem** title font to (Century-Gothic) using  **gothic.ttf** Assets file typeface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside in `styles.xml` add below code

```
<item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/MyActionBar.MenuTextStyle</item>
```

so the styles.xml look like this.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/skyBlue</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
   <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/MyActionBar.MenuTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar.MenuTextStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
   <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>

</style>
```

and then create style for `MyActionBar.MenuTextStyle` and change the `TextView` property as you wish.

> Note : You can only use `custom fonts` via `Java code`, not through
>   layout `XML` or `styles/themes`.

for more detail visit this  : [Set specific font in a styles.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562408/set-specific-font-in-a-styles-xml)

Comment: but hw can i set gothic font style

Comment: @MadhushriM you have to download `gothic font.ttf` file and add it to `assets` folder and then use it.

Comment: ya i have downloaded and saved it in assets folder.....but how to use that file in Style.xml re

Comment: @MadhushriM You can't change `TextFont` in `style` see my update answer.

Comment: Ok ......then how to call that menu title in MainActivity.java bcz in menu.xml  it is not Textview ,its just Title

Comment: @MadhushriM visit this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895472/how-do-i-programmatically-change-actionbar-menuitem-text-colour

Comment: @MadhushriM glad to help you.