# getString() method for a class which extends from LinearLayout

Tags: android, string, android-linearlayout

I have a class which extends from LinearLayout. I want to use a string from string.xml . Normally I use the following code:

```
this.getString(R.string.xxxx);
```

But since my class extends from LinearLayout I can't call getString() method. How can i access those strings which are in my string.xml  from my class?

Comment: you will need the activity context

Comment: you simply need to use getResources() to access the string resources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
getResources().getString(R.string.mystring);
```

or try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17411401/2003486), if you have multiple strings.

Answer (score 1):

You need a context from your Activity class.

1. Create a static global context value in your Activity class.

2.set yourContext in onCreate() method like yourContext=this;

3.Call it in your new class which extened from LinearLayout like:

```
MainActivity.yourContext.getString(R.string.xxxx);
```

Comment: overly complex instead of simply getResources().getString()